# How can I call a JavaScript function from Python using Bokeh?

Tags: javascript, python, function, callback, bokeh

I have this scenario:

1. I have some data (in a pandas dataframe) that I use to draw my plots
2. When I press a button (built by a bokeh widget) I can call my callback method and I do my computation in python.
3. But now I want to send the computed data back to the user in order to show a question in a wizard. So I need to run some JavaScript function.

I was thinking of creating a dummy button and run the click method of this button from python. But I think this is not possible.

So, how can I run a JavaScript function directly from python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.6`, being able to make these kinds of "Remote Procedure Calls" is still an [open feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5983).

In the mean time, your best bet is to add a [`CustomJS` callback](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#userguide-interaction-jscallbacks) to some property of some model. The `CustomJS` can execute whatever JS code you want (including calling other JS functions) and will trigger any the property is updated.

Here's an example that shows calling `CustomJS` whenever a slider is changed. For your use case you might add an invisible circle glyph, and attach a `CustomJS` to the glyph's `size` attribute. Changing `glyph.size` is how you can "call" the function.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show

output_file("js_on_change.html")

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var f = cb_obj.value
    x = data['x']
    y = data['y']
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = column(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example showing what Bryan answered me

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button

plot = figure(
    width=600,
    height=600,
)

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': [1, 2, 3],
    'y': [4, 5, 6],
})
cr = plot.circle(
    x='x', y='y',
    source=source, size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5
)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    console.log('This code will be overwritten')
""")
cr.glyph.js_on_change('size', callback)

def cb():
    js_code = """
        alert('Hello!');
    """
    callback.code = js_code  # update js code
    cr.glyph.size += 1       # trigger the javascript code

bt = Button(
    label="Start Bokeh",
    button_type="success"
)
bt.on_click(cb)

curdoc().add_root(column([bt, plot]))
```