# How to trigger Bokeh actions from the Electron menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, electron, bokeh, rpc

I want to connect a Bokeh Application with Electron. The Electron window already shows the `localhost:5006` of the bokeh application written in Python 3. Now I want to use the native user menu of electron to fire some actions of the Bokeh application. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used some workarounds to achieve that in [this project](https://github.com/ocean-data-qc/ocean-data-qc). Concretely I send signals to the iframe to run some js event and trigger python methods. In the future I hope bokeh will permit some RPC calls. The key files to get the functionality:

1. I load bokeh on an iframe in order to control the whole app from electron.
2. I send the signal to the iframe with [this method](https://github.com/ocean-data-qc/ocean-data-qc/blob/master/ocean_data_qc_js/src/js/renderer_modules/tools.js#L176).

   ```
   document.getElementById('bokeh_iframe').contentWindow.postMessage({
       "signal": "call-python-promise",
       "message_data": message
   } , '*');  // to index.html, the click on the button is run there as well
   ```

   One call example [here](https://github.com/ocean-data-qc/ocean-data-qc/blob/5ad7654976026d4e4aa1261413e67c27e442802f/ocean_data_qc_js/src/js/renderer_modules/server_renderer.js#L44). You can place those calls in the electron menu items (in the ipc renderer side).

   ```
   var call_params = {
       'object': 'bokeh.loader',
       'method': 'init_bokeh',
       'args': {
           'ts_state': $('body').data('ts_state'),
       }
   }
   tools.call_promise(call_params).then((result) => {
       self.run_on_ready();
   });
   ```
3. [This object](https://github.com/ocean-data-qc/ocean-data-qc/blob/master/ocean_data_qc/data_models/electron_bokeh_bridge.py#L35) creates the machinery to trigger callbacks from js. A small bokeh form constructed with a button, a input text and a plot.
4. [Here](https://github.com/ocean-data-qc/ocean-data-qc/blob/master/ocean_data_qc/templates/index.html#L61) I fill the dummy text object to select the method to call (object and method). Then I trigger the python method (callback associated to the button) with `button.click()`
5. The [object and method](https://github.com/ocean-data-qc/ocean-data-qc/blob/master/ocean_data_qc/data_models/electron_bokeh_bridge.py#L120) are received and computed in the python side. Finally, the bokeh method returns the answer to electron with the reversed process as I have exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49095082/4891717).

As you can see this is quite cumbersome. If you find a better way to do it let me know. Some way to call python methods will be created in the future and all of this will be simpler.

**Note**: You may need to check when bokeh is loaded to redirect electron. Check this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794556/how-to-check-if-my-bokeh-server-application-is-completely-loaded-and-rendered/54110237)